# Castle DynamicProxy Interface Proxy Generation

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, aop, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a WindsorContainer.

I have a `ILazyComponentLoader` (if it matters) and an Interface (`ISomething`) with an Interceptor attribute on in.

```
[Interceptor(typeof(DynamicImplementationInterceptor)]
public interface ISomething
```

I want Windsor to use `ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget` when resolving the interface via `container.Resolve<ISomething>()` so that my `DynamicImplementationInterceptor` can implement all behavior on demand, externally.

I can't seem to find this exact scenario in the documentation...when I register `ISomething` by using `Component.For<ISomething>()....`, how do I specify I want this behavior? (presently I get an error about the type being abstract or interface, so it can't be instantiated...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windsor will automatically omit the target when you register a component with an interceptor and no implementation, e.g.:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<DynamicImplementationInterceptor>());
container.Register(Component.For<ISomething>()
    .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<DynamicImplementationInterceptor>()).First);
```

No need for any Interceptor attribute

Comment: Cool thanks. I thought I had tried that and gotten something at registration time about the registration needing an implementation, but I will try agian.